# PostgreSQL Order By not working correctly

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I an working in PostgreSQL database and I want to get data in select query but my order by is not working as I want according to my requirement. How can I achieve this?

right now I am getting  data in below order

```
1
1
1A
10
10
10A
10A
11A
11A
12A
2
2
2A
cradle-1
cradle-2
cradle-11
```

I want to get data in below order.

```
1
1
2
2
10
10
1A
2A
10A
10A
11A
11A
12A
cradle-1
cradle-2
cradle-11
```

below is my select query from which I am getting all data.

```
select am.audit_ques_id, am.audit_id  ,ddl3.dd_value AS activityName  , am.question_id , 
        ddl2.question AS question, am.answer_type, am.answer_lov, ddl4.dd_value AS answerTypeName, am.ok_notok , 
        ddl5.dd_value AS okNotOkName, am.answer_min, am.answer_max, am.uom, ddl13.dd_value AS uomname, 
        am.correct_ans, am.created_by, am.created_date,ddl6.dd_value AS stage, ddl14.dd_value AS stageno, 
        ddl7.description, ddl8.dd_value AS severity, ddl9.dd_value AS who , ddl10.dd_value AS how , 
        ddl11.dd_value AS "when"  , ddl12.dd_value AS "where" from audit_ques_detail am 
        left join audit_master ddl1 on ddl1.audit_id=am.audit_id
        left join dd_type_details ddl3 on ddl3.dd_id=ddl1.activity_id
        left join question_master ddl2 on ddl2.question_id=am.question_id
        left join dd_type_details ddl4 on ddl4.dd_id = am.answer_type
        left join dd_type_details ddl5 on ddl5.dd_id = am.ok_notok
        left join dd_type_details ddl6 on ddl6.dd_id = ddl2.stage
        left join question_master ddl7 on ddl7.question_id = am.question_id
        left join dd_type_details ddl8 on ddl8.dd_id = ddl2.severity
        left join dd_type_details ddl9 on ddl9.dd_id = ddl2.who
        left join dd_type_details ddl10 on ddl10.dd_id = ddl2.how
        left join dd_type_details ddl11 on ddl11.dd_id = ddl2.when
        left join dd_type_details ddl12 on ddl12.dd_id = ddl2.where
        left join dd_type_details ddl13 on ddl13.dd_id = am.uom
        left join dd_type_details ddl14 on ddl14.dd_id = am.stage_no
        where am.audit_id = 1581 and am.isActive = 1 ORDER BY ddl14.dd_value
```

Comment: Could there be data such as `cradle-10` and `cradle-10a`?  This could get complicated.  The best thing to do is to not store numeric and text data in the same column.

Comment: It is sorted correctly but as string/text

Comment: Add the values 'cradle-2' and 'cradle-11' as well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes

Comment: check update sample data in question

Comment: order by length(ddl14.dd_value), ddl14.dd_value ?

Comment: @FatFreddy your solution works and giving order as i want. Please post your solution as answer so i can mark right. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can use several sort condition, first sort for the length of the value and second sort it asc.

```
order by length(ddl14.dd_value), ddl14.dd_value
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how efficient or bulletproof this would be, but you could capture all leading digits with a regex, cast to a number, and then sort by that:

```
order by substring (ddl14.dd_value from '^\d+')::integer, ddl14.dd_value
```

-- EDIT 9/24/2019 --

Again, not looking for efficiency credits, but based on your updated question this sorted in the order you asked for in your sample data:

```
order by
  substring (ddl14.dd_value from '^\d+')::integer, 
  substring (ddl14.dd_value from '\D+') nulls first,
  substring (ddl14.dd_value from '\d+$')::integer
```

Sample output:

```
1
1
2
2
10
10
10A
10A
11A
11A
12A
cradle-1
cradle-2
cradle-11
```

Comment: Thanx @Hambone. I want numeric value first then alphanumeric and the full string value.

Comment: I *think* that code snippet will do that...  does it not?

Comment: check my updated sample data in question. what I want

Comment: Looks like your Order by logic will be more complicated than the actual select criteria. For example where the values '1dawle2', '1dawle-10' and '10dawle-0' fall into the list. BTW the desired order indicated you want does not follow the stated "numeric value first then alphanumeric". Look at position of item "1A"  following item "10"  but well after item "2" thus distorting the numeric first rule.

Comment: Aah, that does change things...  see update and check if that helps or not

Comment: Unfortunately revised seems to have totally dropped "1A" and '2A', but even so would not produce the desired result with "1A" after 10.

Comment: Thanx everyone for your answer. Answer of @FatFreddy worked for me.

Comment: @Belayer - you are saying an order by altered the actual output, not just the order of the output?

Comment: I'm saying the order by clause will not produce the desired order specified. It will produce a sequence:  1,1,1A, ... not the desired order 1,1,2,2,10,1A.  Basically the desired order will require a custom sort routine as the high level is neither numeric not alpha but a mixture.